# What are the Equivalent methods to CopyTo() and WriteTo() in .Net Framework 3.5 and below?

Tags: c#, .net-framework-version

I need to use .NetFramework3.5 for my application, but `CopyTo()` and `WriteTo()` methods are not available in 3.5.  what are the equivalent methods in 3.5?

when I run the code with 3.5 it is throwing the following error:

> 'System.IO.Stream' does not contain a definition for 'WriteTo' and no extension method 'WriteTo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.Stream' could be found

Here is the code:

```
int fileId = 1;
foreach (string uri in uriList)
{

    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (baseURL + uri);
    request.Headers.Add ("X", authenticateStr);
    request.Accept = "application/pdf";
    request.Method = "GET";

    webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (FileStream outfile = new FileStream("document_", FileMode.Create)) {
        webResponse.GetResponseStream().WriteTo(ms);
        if (ms.Length > int.MaxValue) {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot write a file larger than 2GB.");
        }
        outfile.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Done!");
```

Comment: From MSDN - "When the current stream is open, this method is equivalent to calling Stream.Write on the underlying buffer of this stream." So just create a extension method.

Comment: Try to find out your solution from below link

[Link1][1]

[Link2][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985795/gzipstream-copyto-alternate-and-easy-way-in-net-3-5
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730863/how-to-use-stream-copyto-on-framework-3-5

Comment: How to use the extension method in my code?  Now I' m using webResponse.GetResponseStream().WriteTo(ms); what are the modifications to be done to the above code?

Comment: I created the extension method, how to use this in the code?

Answer (score 2):

1. [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992542.aspx) was indeed added with .NET 4. Earlier versions of .NET are missing lots of helpful methods added in latter versions. .NET 4.5 continues to have lots of "obvious" method missing, I assume future versions will continue to add such helpers if MS perceive sufficient demand.
2. There is no [`Stream.WriteTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts2303ww.aspx). It only exists on some subclasses (eg. [`MemoryStream.WriteTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.writeto.aspx) which has existed since .NET 1.0).

(I suspect `Stream.CopyTo` was added as a common `MemoryStream.WriteTo` but obviously using `WriteTo` would be an API breaking change because, for example, reflection on it would give different results.)

Answer (score 1):

If you need for CopyTo I use this extension

```
public static void CopyTo(this Stream input, Stream output)
{
   // This method exists only in .NET 4 and higher

   byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
   int bytesRead;

   while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
   {
      output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   }
}
```